# Github jenkins webhook integration failed

Tags: jenkins, github

I am trying to configure webhooks in github so that it will build every time I do a new push, I have added web hooks in github and given the address of jenkins which is http://localhost:8080/github-webhook/ but it did not work and I found out that we need to find our IP address and I added it as follows: http://"my IPV4":8080/github-webhook/ and it still didn't work. I have even tried using ngrok to port forward, but it didn't work as well. It constantly throws the `We couldn’t deliver this payload: Failure when receiving data from the peer` error.

Answer (score 0):

You need a public IP address for Github to point to detect a push request. `localhost` is on your local machine. You can configure jenkins on EC2 if you want to set it up for some testing.

You can use a proxy agent Ngrok.

Command :

`ngrok http 8080`

It will generate `http://{some-number}.ngrok.io`, copy the generated public address and put in your github repository webhook `http://{some-number}.ngrok.io/github-webhook`

At this point when you save it, it will send a post request to ngrok server, got redirected to localhost and you will see a green tick.

You can refer to this [document](https://medium.com/@developerwakeling/setting-up-github-webhooks-jenkins-and-ngrok-for-local-development-f4b2c1ab5b6) for configuring the whole process.

Comment: Thank you!! I have tried using ngrok as well but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user8211795 You can easily utilize EC2 on AWS to achieve it if that's not a concern. Refer document that I shared, it might help you with ngrok. In my case, it works.

Answer (score 0):

1- first install ngrok and run command ngrok http 8080 ==> ( write any port )
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5J42.png)

2- take the ip end to (ngrok.io)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEl44.png)

3- add webhook in repo on  github and Make sure it's Works well

(ex: https://xxx-xxx-xx-xx-xx.eu.ngrok.io/github-webhook/)

choose:

- Content type : application/json
- Enable SSL
- Just the push event , Active

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqkMd.png)

4- finally add any file or edit commit , now the jenkins listen to update